# Can the network administrator know if a port is connected to a router or a laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

So our college hostel has some Wi-Fi along the halls, but they are overcrowded (too many users connected to the Wi-Fi), so I usually don't have a stable connection.

We now have personal LAN ports in our rooms, but that is not as user-friendly as a Wi-Fi connection would have. But our network administrator issued guidelines that mention we can't use routers in our rooms, as this would clog the network (hence, it will slow down the speed for others). Now I have two questions.

1. One is that if it considerably affects the network if a single user
   uses a router like this?
2. And can the network administrator know that a router is connected to
   the port instead or a computer? Or at least guess that something
   fishy is going on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably. The router will have a MAC address, and MAC addresses are allocated by manufacturer (and possibly by product type as well). If your network admins look at the switch or router at *their* end, and see a MAC address that is allocated to (e.g.) Cisco for LinkSys router devices, they'll know that you have a LinkSys router attached.

They can probably also see multiple MAC addresses on a port if you have a computer connected to your (unapproved) router, which is another "giveaway".

As far as affecting the network... yes, if you have multiple devices causing traffic on the network, it will affect network performance. However, this question is irrelevant under the circumstances; you're not allowed to use the router, so even if it *improved* network performance for everyone, you'd still be in violation and subject to any sanctions that they might choose to impose.

Comment: Good point abt the multiple MAC situation. I forgot all abt it. If the admin knows their job, they've set up a MAC restriction on the switch port anyway to prevent connecting multiple devices, and so the port will shut down all by itself.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I can use the personal WiFi easily (I had already set it up before asking the question, will have to take it down now). But there is a red flicker in the LOS signal, but I am able to use the internet. So, it seems they have not set the restriction you mentioned. But, it will be better to take it down, as I have heard that some of my seniors had their routers seized.

Comment: But, one common practice in our hostel is to connect our Laptop using the LAN port and then use the hotspot functionality (Share Internet Connectivity in Mac) to create kind of personal WiFi and connect our phones to that. Is connecting a router to the LAN much different? This practice which I mentioned has not received any action from the IT department.

Comment: It depends on what the IT department sees - if too many people do that, and it adversely and visibly impacts the network, they may try to investigate, and if ICS is functionally equivalent to having a router there, they might well detect it and issue sanctions. It may not be a priority for them to go after those users though; most university IT departments are underfunded and understaffed and the networks under-specced, and so they'll have a lot more to do just to keep the network running and manage the university's computers. But when they do a sweep, you and a dozen other people may get hit.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I am not sure if ICS is equivalent to the router. But, they seem to do the same job to me though. Like creating a wifi kind of thing. Our IT department hasn't done any checks yet in the 2 years I have been here, and I use the ICS functionality quite frequently as do most of my friends. So, taking this into consideration. I am probably safe to use my router. or using a router would be too different from ICS.

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra I've no idea what a "LOS signal" is, unless it's the "Loss of Signal" abbreviation :-) If I was running the network, I'd probably allow 2 - 3 MAC addresses per port to accommodate multi-device users. If you've had your own AP there the IT guys may not consider that a potential threat but I would either take it down or have it officially accepted to avoid trouble.

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra - IT hasn't done any checks _that you know of_, or _that they have chosen to take action on_. Don't assume that either of those situations will continue to obtain. If you use your router, you could get hit at any time. You do it at your own risk. Ditto ICS.

Comment: `They can probably also see multiple MAC addresses on a port if you have a computer connected to your (unapproved) router` @Peregrino69 A router literally means a device that *IP forwards* (this does NOT mean DNAT btw) from one network (BD) to another. Regardless of whether source NAT is involved, that literally in turn means the hosts on the destination network (or, "WAN") will see only *frames* with source MAC of the *interface* that is in the network (or, the WAN interface). They will only see frames with different source MACs if what you attached to it is (just) a switch.

Comment: With that said though, I'm not ruling out other information in certain kind of traffics could "leak" the fact that there's more than one host "behind the scene". (Btw, of course by one source MAC in the previous comment obviously I excluded all the "special" ones.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Potentially. I personally don't think this is the main reason, but any network admin worth his salt will not allow rogue routers in his network.
2. Absolutely.

What you could do is get a cheap AP instead of a router to connect to the Ethernet. An AP is really nothing more than a dumb network interface just like a NIC. That would allow you to set up your own SSID.

***HOWEVER***

Exactly the same applies here: the network admin will know there's a rogue AP and there will be consequences, the first one being shutting down the LAN port. So before doing even that you need to agree on it with the network admin. Just to prepare you for the disappointment, I don't expect them to be amenable to this either.

Probably the best is just bite the bullet and remember "When in Rome..."

Comment: I can hardly see how an AP is potentially a better option in this context, due to the facts I've pointed out in the other answer. But well, unless you never meant "better" (but really just cheaper). (Or, maybe you mean the OP can argue that, "hey this is not a router and only routers are said to be forbidden", heh...)

Comment: LOL ya got it mate :-D